# Update URL with input from user in Shiny APP

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with an shiny app and i'd like to create an query with an action button that updates the url according to the user input (in this case, a textInput `input$query_user`).

For example, this is my ip: http://127.0.0.1:6858

And after the user fills the `textInput`, clicks an action button it would upload the url to http://127.0.0.1:6858/?lookfor=query_user

I've seen this post:
[R shiny: Add weblink to actionButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795760/r-shiny-add-weblink-to-actionbutton)

but it doesn't work, because the example does not reads my input.

```
actionButton(inputId='query_button',
             label="Search", 
             icon = icon("th"), 
             onclick = paste("location.href='http://127.0.0.1:6858?lookfor=",
                             input$query_user, "'", sep="))
  )
)
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/updateQueryString.html. Rather than "navigating" you can just update the querystring.

Comment: There's a typo in the code you posted: the `sep` argument is incomplete

Comment: @MrFlick i've used that example you showed me, but how could i change this "For mode = "push", only three updates are currently allowed:

the query string (format: ?param1=val1&param2=val2)" to my personal format (?lookfor=) thanks