# Embed a hyperlink with multiple parameters in an actionButton shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, href, action-button

I am using a hyper link that I would like to pass into a shiny action button. I would like to use the "onclick" feature in the action button however, I have multiple parameters that are in my hyperlink which i am unsure how to pass into the action button.

For example here is my current hyper link in shiny that works.

```
a("Profile",href="https://predicting-alpha.outseta.com/widgets/profile#o-authenticated", id = "profileLink")
```

I would like to have a shiny button with the above link in the button (no new window opening).
Here is what I was thinking but this does not seem to work. Thank you for your time.

```
actionButton("test", "test", onclick = "https://predicting-alpha.outseta.com/widgets/profile#o-authenticated", id = "profileLink")
```

Comment: Do you want your user redirected to the URL?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795760/r-shiny-add-weblink-to-actionbutton) help?

Comment: @andrew_reece it does not. I saw that prior but that opens up a new window and does not have multiple inputs

Comment: @HubertL no the link should create a pop up on the same screen